# Using HttpPatch without violating encapsulation

Tags: asp.net, rest

I have problem about HttpPatch which violate encapsulation of domain model. I using ASP.NET Core

**Let's start with an example:** I have a customer domain model which has some attributes and behaviour to imagine it better

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string Firstname { get; private set; }
    public string Lastname { get; private set; }

    public System.DateTime BirthDate { get; private set; }


    public void UpdateName(string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        /*
         * Some validations here for example first name first latter should be uppercase and so on..
         */

        Firstname = firstname;
        Lastname = lastname;
    }

    public void UpdateBirthDate(System.DateTime BirthDate)
    {
        /*
         * Some validations here for example age must be greater than 18
         */
        this.BirthDate = BirthDate;
    }
}
```

As you can see above we have a customer domain model which has private setters and has method which is used to update domain model properties. So to update Firstname and Lastname you gonna call "UpdateName" - method which validates data and after that it will update this model. Also it could throw some domain events if necessary.

Also I'm using Rest architecture in my API. So I have some method where I need to update my customer model partially here is also example:

```
    [HttpPatch]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<WorkDay> document)
    {
        var testCustomer = new Customer();
        document.ApplyTo(testCustomer);

        return Content("Success");
    }
```

So right now let's talk about problem about above code. Let's imagine that testCustomer pulled from storage. After that we update our storage customer by calling ApplyTo. The problem here actually is that it directly sets values to appropriate property which violates encapsulation also the problem in this approach is that it is not calling my methods to throw some domain events or do some validations and so on...

What is workaround of this problem ? Is there any extension which helps me to map those changes to appropriate methods ?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem here actually is that it directly sets values to appropriate property which violates encapsulation

The semantics of the HTTP methods are those of a document store.  The client has a representation of the resource, it wants the server's representation to match.  The entire exchange is fundamentally anemic.

Thus, you end up running into concerns similar to those which encouraged [task based user interfaces](https://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/), which is to say exchanging messages that describe domain semantics, rather than document semantics.

Options:

You can stay with the document semantics, and write code to compute the differences between the server's representation of the document and the client's, translate that difference into domain messages, and apply them to the model.

You can replace the patch document -- instead of using json-patch, you could use your own domain specific patch media type, that describes changes in domain semantics.  That makes things easy for the server, but you lose support for general purpose components.

You can change your resource model -- instead of sending changes to the document that is the representation of the domain model, you can send changes to the document that is the representation of the messages being sent to the domain model.

You can use form semantics (POST) to describe client changes, rather than using remote authoring semantics

With information that doesn't belong to you (your model isn't the authority for `FirstName` or `BirthDate` -- you are just caching a copy of data provided to you), you might consider separating the model (their data is not the same as our data), or performing the validation on the input (which is to say, walking through the patch-document first, then applying the changes to the model).

But no joke; there are some real tensions when you try to cross from the document domain into your model.  See [Webber 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) for more.